# Laplace’s equation in three dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to solve 
Laplace’s equation in a cube??

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}=0, 0 <x,y,z< \pi \\ 
u(\pi,y,z)=g(y,z)\\ 
u(0,y,z)=u(x,0,z)=u(x,\pi,z)=u(x,y,0)=u(x,y,\pi)=0
\end{matrix}\right.$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try separation of variables, i.e. look for solutions that can be written $a(x)b(y)c(z)$. Then take superpositions of such solutions to match the boundary conditions.

Comment: Your last boundary condition is probably wrongly typed. Please check.

Comment: @Tunococ thanks, updated

Comment: Have you tried separation of variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard song and dance with separation of variables yields

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
X'' + \mu X = 0, & X(0) = 0 \\
Y'' - \lambda Y = 0, & Y(0)=Y(\pi)=0 \\
Z'' - (\mu - \lambda)Z = 0, & Z(0)=Z(\pi)=0
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

The standard song and dance with ODE yields

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\lambda = -n^2, \mu = -(n^2 + m^2), & n, m \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \\
X(x) = \sinh\left(\left[\sqrt{n^2  + m^2}\right]x\right) \\
Y(y) = \sin(ny) \\
Z(z) = \sin(mz)
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

Slapping everything together, we find

$$u(x,y,z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} b_{nm} \sinh\left(\left[\sqrt{n^2  + m^2}\right]x\right) \sin(ny) \sin(mz)$$

Applying the final boundary condition $u(\pi,y,z) = g(y,z)$,

$$g(y,z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} b_{nm} \sinh\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2  + m^2}\right) \sin(ny) \sin(mz)$$

says that we need a multiple Fourier sine series for $g(y,z)$. It remains to find the Fourier coefficients $b_{nm}$. Multiply by $\sin(ky)$ and $\sin(lz)$ and integrate through (using orthogonality) to obtain:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} g(y,z) \sin(ny) \sin(mz) dy dz = \frac{\pi^2}{4} b_{nm} \sinh\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2  + m^2}\right) $$

Solving for $b_{nm}$ yields a formal solution. Given a specific $g(y,z)$, just plug it in and carry out the integration; then substitute the result for $b_{nm}$ back into the series solution for $u(x,y,z)$.

I've left out a lot of the details and encourage you to fill them in.